# Remove shadow effect on background color during page transition

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm making an application with SwiftUI that has a blue background color, so I did that by something like this:

```swift
// MainView
var body: some View {
  NavigationView {
    ZStack {
      Color("ThemeColor").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
      Color("BgColor")
      VStack {
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView() {
          Text("View Details")
        })
        // ...
      }
    }
  }
}

// DetailView
var body: some View {
  ZStack {
    Color("ThemeColor").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    Color("BgColor")
    VStack {
      Text("Details Page")
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

I gave the status bar a blue background(`ThemeColor`) and the page itself a white(`BgColor`) background. This works as expected, but when I press a Navigation Link, the animation is a bit weird:
[image: Transition]

A shadow effect appears on the status bar, which makes the animation look awkward. Can I remove this shadow effect? It would be better if the shadow on the page itself (the white part) will be not removed.

Comment: This needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), colors included.

Comment: @Yrb I just edited that.

Comment: That is not an MRE. You have to be able to take that code, open a new project, build and run it, or come up with the same errors if it won't build. Rather than using the name `ThemeColor` and `BgColor` put the actual colors in. You are asking for help, and then making us do extra work to try to help you. Think about that and the number of comments/answers you have. The two are related.

Comment: Did you figure this out? @JongwooLee